# Adding extra info on the join table when creating new records on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a join table for has_many through relation. I have added one field on the join table `type`, I know want when I create a new model emnima to store on the jointable the type of the user

```
has_one :emnima_admin, -> { where type: 'admin' }, class_name: 'EmnimasUser', dependent: :nullify, inverse_of: :admin
has_one :admin, through: :emnima_admin, class_name: 'Admin'


admin = Admin.create!
admin.emnima.create!()
admin.emnimas  # works just fine
admin.emnimata.admin   # this is null since the emnima_admin record is nil, how can I set the type field of the join_table when I am creating the emnima entry?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by just doing `create` on the join table.

```rb
JoinTable.create(user_id: current_user.id, other_foreign_key: some_id, type: 'admin', ....)
```